# Redux-form throws error onDragStart in FF

Tags: redux-form

Using redux, when I select text in an input and drag the selection, I get an error:

`Error: Permission denied to access property "setData"`

It seems there is a related issue [here](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/597), but no solution.

Is there a workaround to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround: override the onDragStart so that `redux-form` doesn't throw.

`const handleDragStart = (e) => {}
// jsx
<input
    ...
    onDragStart={handleDragStart}
/>`